# How to make summary table by group in r?

Tags: r, summary

I want make a summary table by group in R
compare several parameter by factor
For example

```
data(iris)
str(iris)
```

i wanna make table

```
     Group   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
  Species1        mean       mean        mean       mean
  Species2        mean       mean        mean       mean
  Species3        mean       mean        mean       mean
```

possible import t.test result
How do i do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
data(iris) 
aggregate(iris[,1:4], list(iris$Species), mean)
```

Comment: actually my data set is [ Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 446 obs. of  23 variables] numeric data is 6:23. type upper code, i saw error message like this 'list(df3$region)' is not a function, character or symbol.. what wrong?

Comment: Show your data snipet by dput(datafile)

Comment: Check if the non-numeric variable called `region` is not between the 6th and the 23rd column